# How to set 301 redirection after moving WordPress blog?

Tags: redirect, htaccess, seo, wp-redirect

I have moved my wordpress blog to new domain.

Old Address : **domainname.com/blog** |
New Address : **newdomainname.com**

Please pay attention about **old address and new address**.

Now I want to redirect all old pages to new blog ( should be 30 redirection).

I could not find way to do it properly because I moved my blog to new domain from old domain directory.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### WAY #1 - cPanel

I assume your host is using cPanel managing your Server.

Browse `domainname.com/cpanel`, login their with cPanel credential:
[image]

Change the values according the following image:
[image]

Don't forget to check the "Wildcard Redirect" to redirect all the subfolder/subpages also (*Thanks to @RobertHue*). *Add* the redirection and you are done.

#### WAY #2 - `.htaccess`

Open up your `.htaccess` of `domainname.com/blog/` in edit mode. Put the following code there (I made it using [WebConfs.com Redirect Generator](http://www.webconfs.com/htaccess-redirect-generator.php)):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://newdomainname.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Save it. And *yala*!

### EDIT

That's well said by @RobertHue. I did not mention the subfolder or subpages redirection. So I edited my answer, changed the attached images and posted new code. Thanks a lot @RobertHue for pointing the important things.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your answer :-) I will try this one. :-)

Comment: You didn't consider redirecting pages/posts in your solution.

Comment: Roberthue: Thanks a lot. I fixed my Answer now. @Sasa1234 please check the new answer and follow accordingly.

Comment: I tried way 1. Even I select Wildcard Redirect, redirecting works for only home page :-(

Answer (score 0):

Below query will help you to replace old pages to new domain :

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.oldsiteurl.com', 'http://www.newsiteurl.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple redirect, where we are trying to send a user visiting an old post to a new post.

```
Redirect 301 /a-very-old-post/ /a-very-new-post/
```

You can add the code above preferably at the start of your .htaccess file.